# How do I prevent libvirt from adding iptables rules for guest NAT networks?

Tags: iptables, kvm-virtualization, libvirt

Similar to [this](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=433484) old request on BugZilla for Fedora 8, I'm hoping something has changed since then or someone knows another way.

I want to manage the iptables rules by hand—the one-size-fits-all automatic rules don't suit me at all. These rules seem to be added and removed when a network is started and destroyed. Is there a way of either preventing these rules being added at all or hooking a script into the network start that restores the default rules afterwards.

For now, I'm using a very crude method with `cron`, but I hope there is a better way:

```
  *  *  *  *  * root    iptables-restore < /etc/sysconfig/iptables
```

Comment: Is KVM using a modular script to start virtual network devices? If so you could manipulate that script (this is how I would do this on XEN).

Comment: I don't think so but tbh I'm not sure how to find out.

Comment: The best place to ask is the libvirt devel list or on their IRC channel (#virt on OFTC)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well I've found an answer that suits me: I've gone back to school and learned to do it the old fashioned way. No need to use libvirt's fancy networking functions as I can just:

- set up my own bridged network(s) (not attached to any physical network port)
- use a DHCP server on the host and masquerade in iptables
- edit the libvirt guest config files to use the bridge(s)
- have complete flexibility in how I want to configure security with iptables

Comment: +1 just use bridged mode, or move on to 802.1Qbg/h

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to modify these rules, since they are not in a configuration file or a script, but in the sourcecode.

But in 2016 the "open"-network "forward mode" was added. When specified for a network, libvirt does not generate any iptables rules for the network. [See bug 846810](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=846810).

So edit your network (`virsh net-edit`) to **`<forward mode='open'/>`**.

`open` is like `route`, but there will be no firewall rules added to either enable or prevent any of this traffic.
See [Network XML format](https://libvirt.org/formatnetwork.html#elementsConnect) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Use hooks to restore your iptables rules:

```bash
# The "hooks/" folder is not created by default by Libvirt
mkdir /etc/libvirt/hooks

# Libvirt supports multiple possible listeners like "daemon", "qemu", etc. 
# We are generating automatically all of these listeners in one go.
for f in daemon qemu lxc libxl network; do

  echo '#!/bin/sh
iptables-restore < /etc/sysconfig/iptables' > "/etc/libvirt/hooks/$f"
  chmod +x "/etc/libvirt/hooks/$f"

done

# Restarting Libvirt to confirm that rules are actually restored
service libvirtd restart
```

Iptables rules will be reloaded for certain actions only, but this is sufficient to make it static. Only reload (`SIGHUP`) of libvirtd will write it's own rules, but it isn't triggered by any system scripts, so will not happen until you type by yourself:

```bash
service libvirtd reload
```

See https://libvirt.org/hooks.html

**UPDATE:**
Recent libvirt versions use its own chains to insert rules and these chains are required to start/stop networks and domains. So the previous way won't work. Here are these chains in `iptables-restore` format:

```
*mangle
:LIBVIRT_PRT - [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -j LIBVIRT_PRT
*filter
:LIBVIRT_FWI - [0:0]
:LIBVIRT_FWO - [0:0]
:LIBVIRT_FWX - [0:0]
:LIBVIRT_INP - [0:0]
:LIBVIRT_OUT - [0:0]
-A INPUT -j LIBVIRT_INP
-A FORWARD -j LIBVIRT_FWX
-A FORWARD -j LIBVIRT_FWI
-A FORWARD -j LIBVIRT_FWO
-A OUTPUT -j LIBVIRT_OUT
*nat
:LIBVIRT_PRT - [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -j LIBVIRT_PRT
```

To override libvirtd rules just put your custom rules before the libvirt-jump rule (-j LIBVIRT_XXX). When libvirtd/network/domain starts it only inserts jump-rules if they don't exist. So all you need is load your rules (with all libvirt chains created and libvirt-jump rules correctly placed) before libvirtd starts. From another point of view - you need to restart/reload libvirtd every time after changing and loading your new rules - to let it insert libvirt's ones.

Answer (score 2):

[Per Red Hat Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=433484):

> First, it is already possible to avoid the iptables rules - simply do not
> request a NAT based virtual network. The 'default' virtual network is
> intentionally NAT based. You are free to remove this & default one which doesn't provide NAT.

So to avoid the cron job:

```
virsh net-destroy default
virsh net-undefine default
```

Of course, as @user83664 wrote, you'll have to use either a bridge or hostonly networks going forward.